# Issue in Alphanumeric sorting with special char

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to sort an alphanumeric value containing some special characters in sql server, I have tried several order by clause but it is not giving the desired output( It is giving the output as 1,10,100 than 101 it should be 1,2,3..100 )
I have tried ordering by alphabets and number at same time by split but it didn't worked.

Comment: Show us the things we can't guess, like the data types, some actual values (including all edge cases, like starts with, ends with, contains, doesn't contain), and the desired order.

Comment: Hi Aron, the values are : CBSFBE20151202000017_000_1.tif
CBSFBE20151202000017_000_10.tif
CBSFBE20151202000017_000_2.tif
CBSFBE20151202000017_000_3.tif
CBSFBE20151202000017_000_4.tif
CBSFBE20151202000017_000_5.tif

Comment: Great, please add those to the question, as well as how you want them sorted in the output. Also add other edge cases so we don't have to guess at those, either. e.g. `CBSFBE20151202000017_000_0.tif`, `CBSFBE20151202000017_000.tif`, `CBSFBE20151202000017_000_1.tif`, `DBSFBE20151202000017_000_1.tif`, `CBSFBF20151202000017_000_1.tif`, `CBSFBE20151202000016_000_1.tif`, `CBSFBE20151202000018_000_1.tif` ... that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution. The first, I create a function that gets number from the string. And then sort this number.

```
USE tempdb
GO
CREATE TABLE MyTable (ID INT, Col1 VARCHAR(100))
GO
-----
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, Col1)
SELECT 1, 'CBSFBE20151202000017_000_1.tif'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'CBSFBE20151202000017_000_10.tif'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'CBSFBE20151202000017_000_2.tif'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'CBSFBE20151202000017_000_3.tif'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'CBSFBE20151202000017_000_11.tif'

-----
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGetNumberFromString (@strInput VARCHAR(255)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @intNumber int 
    SET @intNumber = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strInput)
    WHILE @intNumber > 0
    BEGIN 
        SET @strInput = STUFF(@strInput, @intNumber, 1, '')
        SET @intNumber = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strInput)
    END 

    RETURN ISNULL(@strInput,0) 
END 
GO

-----
SELECT *, dbo.fnGetNumberFromString(Col1) AS Number
FROM MyTable
order by CAST(dbo.fnGetNumberFromString(Col1) AS float), Col1
```

Comment: What if there is a value `x345`? The question is unclear enough that I'd hold off on answering.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Yeah! You're right. But it's just a solution for him to refer.

Comment: The values which i need to sort are as below: CBSFBE20151202000017_000_1.tif CBSFBE20151202000017_000_10.tif CBSFBE20151202000017_000_2.tif CBSFBE20151202000017_000_3.tif CBSFBE20151202000017_000_4.tif CBSFBE20151202000017_000_5.tif

Comment: @amit.91121: It's Ok. I edited my answer following your sample data.